# I got a vehicle at around 92300 miles , however I want to change my oil to make sure it has synthetic high mileage oil

Tags: oil-change, ram

I got my 2018 ram 1500 last month had around 92300 miles , and I’m no over 93200 miles , I put on over 1000 miles and I would like to put in synthetic oil and change the oil filter as well , to make sure it has the best oil , should I wait or I’m all good to change the oil

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the oil whenever you want. It doesn't make a difference. Just get it done before it actually needs it. You won't hurt anything by changing it early.